# How to join selected lines in a RichTextBox with a specific character and replace the existing lines?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, richtextbox

I want to join selected line in RichTextBox and separate those two lines with specific character.

```
The situation is dire
But momma raised up a fighter
It's all come down to the wire
But the come-up is higher
```

result:

```
The situation is dire - But momma raised up a fighter
```

or

```
It's all come down to the wire - But the come-up is higher
```

The new line generated should replace the existing lines in the Control.

Comment: It looks like you want to replace a linebreak (vbCrLf) with a hyphen. Is that correct?

Comment: @tgolisch Dear tgolisch yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim StartSelection As Integer = RichTextBox1.SelectionStart
    Dim EndSelection As Integer = RichTextBox1.SelectionStart + RichTextBox1.SelectionLength
    Dim StartLine As Integer = 0
    Dim EndLine As Integer = 0
    Dim Position As Integer = 0
    Dim Pos As Integer = 0
    Dim Index As Integer = 0

    For i = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1
        Position += RichTextBox1.Lines(i).Length
        If StartSelection <= Position Then
            StartLine = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Position = 0
    For i = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1
        Position += RichTextBox1.Lines(i).Length
        If Position >= EndSelection Then
            EndLine = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If EndLine = 0 Then
        EndLine = RichTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1
    Else
        EndLine -= 1
    End If
    If Not StartLine = EndLine Then
        Do
            Pos += RichTextBox1.Lines(Index).Length

            If Index = StartLine Then
                Exit Do
            Else
                Index += 1
            End If
        Loop
        Pos -= RichTextBox1.Lines(Index).Length
        For i = StartLine To EndLine - 1
            If i = StartLine Then
                RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Remove(Pos + RichTextBox1.Lines(Index).Length + i, 1).Insert(Pos + RichTextBox1.Lines(Index).Length + i, " - ")
                RichTextBox1.Refresh()
            Else
                RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Remove(Pos + RichTextBox1.Lines(Index).Length + StartLine, 1).Insert(Pos + RichTextBox1.Lines(Index).Length + StartLine, " - ")
                RichTextBox1.Refresh()
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

I recommend placing the code in the mouse-up event of the Textbox or RichTextbox.

Comment: Dear DarrenPeterson, This code is for combining lines 0 and 1, but what should I do if I want to combine other lines That's why I asked in my questions I want to join selected line in RichTextBox

Comment: @vahidAraghi have modified my answer for multiple lines.

Comment: Dear DarrenPeterson, thank you for helping me but With this new code, when I select two lines this code Considers all lines, but I want to Just combine the two lines I selected.

Comment: @vahidAraghi Now you can select the lines that you want to combine.

Comment: WOW, this is magic, it's works like a charm, thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. Also thanks for giving me a challenge to complete!

Answer (score 1):

An example using both [string.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join) and LINQ's [Aggregate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate) methods, to fill a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder) that acts as an *accumulator* for the lines of text.
A StringBuilder object is a convenient storage when dealing with strings, it can limit the number of strings that will need garbage collection after use.

LINQ's [Skip()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip) and [Take()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take) method are also used to *Skip* the specified number of elements in a collection and *Take* a specified number of elements.
Note that `Take()` doesn't overflow: if the number of elements to take is more than what's available, it just takes what it can find.

I've mixed `string.Join()` and `Aggregate()` to show their use, you can actually perform all actions using one or the other.

Using `Aggregate()`, the last chars in the StringBuilder are determined by [Environment.NewLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline) and need to be removed.
Note that the [StringBuilder.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.tostring) method allows to generate a sub-string of the content.
If you use `String.Join()` instead, you don't need to strip the trailing chars.

You can call the `MergeLines()` method as:

```
RichTextBox1.Text = MergeLines(RichTextBox1.Text, 1, 4)
```

to merge 4 the lines of text in a RichTextBox, from line 1 to line 4.
If you have 6 lines and you want to merge all, then specify:

```
RichTextBox1.Text = MergeLines(RichTextBox1.Text, 0, 5)
```

The method checks whether the starting and ending lines specified express line values that are compatible with the content of the text.

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text

Private Function MergeLines(text As String, lineStart As Integer, lineEnd As Integer) As String
    Dim lines = text.Split(ControlChars.Lf)
    If lines.Length < 2 OrElse (lineStart < 0 OrElse lineEnd >= lines.Length) Then Return text

    Dim sb = lines.Take(lineStart).
        Aggregate(New StringBuilder(), Function(s, ln) s.AppendLine(ln))
    sb.AppendLine(String.Join(" - ", lines.Skip(lineStart).Take(lineEnd - lineStart + 1)))
    lines.Skip(lineEnd + 1).Aggregate(sb, Function(s, ln) s.AppendLine(ln))
    Return sb.ToString(0, sb.Length - Environment.NewLine.Length)
End Function
```

---

Description of the first line of code that aggregates string elements to a StringBuilder:

```
Dim sb = lines.
    Take(lineStart).
    Aggregate(New StringBuilder(), 
        Function(s, ln) s.AppendLine(ln)
```

- Using the `lines` collection:

  - Take `lineStart` number of lines. `lineStart` is the first line to merge: if `lineStart = 2` - the third line - then take 2 lines, thus lines `0` and `1`).
  - Aggregate in a new StringBuilder object each line taken. The StringBuilder appends each line plus `Environment.NewLine`.
- The result of the aggregation is a filled StringBuilder object.

---

C# version:

```
private string MergeLines(string text, int start, int end)
{
    var lines = text.Split('\n'); ;
    if (lines.Length < 2 || (start < 0 || end >= lines.Length)) return text;

    var sb = lines.Take(start).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (s, ln) => s.AppendLine(ln));
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(" - ", lines.Skip(start).Take(end - start + 1)));
    lines.Skip(end + 1).Aggregate(sb, (s, ln) => s.AppendLine(ln));
    return sb.ToString(0, sb.Length - Environment.NewLine.Length);
}
```